# "start" and "begin", is there a difference?

Tags: difference, synonyms

Today, when looking up the definitions of the phrasal verb "take something up", I noticed that one of them was written like this: ***"to start** or **begin** something such as a job.*" For the first time I realized that maybe "start" and "begin" don't exactly mean the same thing.

So the question is what is the difference between these two? And are there cases when they mean exactly the same thing?

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a few phrases where you think the meanings are the same or not or you can't tell. Otherwise its a vague question due to all the possibilities.

Comment: You can find the answer [here][1] in the friendly site .


  [1]: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21043/what-is-the-difference-between-begin-and-start

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a great many contexts, ***to start*** and ***to begin*** are effectively synonyms, but there are plenty of contexts where they aren't.

1. You can only ***start*** your car (make the engine begin running). You can't ***begin*** the car.
2. A loud noise can only make you ***start*** (be startled)
3. You can ***start out on*** a journey (or just ***start***, or ***begin***, but not ***begin out on*** a journey)
4. Idiomatic *"Don't [you] **start**!"* (just keep out of this argument!) doesn't work with ***begin***.

I'm sure there are many other cases I haven't included. But the general rule is that where the meaning is *to commence*, the two words are interchangeable (though in some contexts one might be more *likely* than the other).

Comment: You [start a fire](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFTLKWw542g) but you [begin the beguine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cCYGyg1H56s)